# Slick Slider. Не работают breakpoints в Google Chrome

Tags: slick.js

Есть простая тестовая страница определенно для Slick Slider. Код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700,400&amp;subset=latin,cyrillic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/common.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="responsive">
                <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"/></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"/></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"/></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"/></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"/></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"/></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"/></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"/></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"/></div>
                <div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"/></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/common.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Инициализирую слик, точно как на сайте:

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){ 

    $('.responsive').slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: false,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 4,
        responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 1024,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3,
                slidesToScroll: 3,
                infinite: true,
                dots: true
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 600,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 2,
                slidesToScroll: 2
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1
            }
        }
        // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
        // settings: "unslick"
        // instead of a settings object
        ]
    }); 

});
```

В Mozilla брейкпоинты отрабатывают правильно:
[image: Breakpoints на Mozilla]

В Chrome:

[image: Breakpoints на Chrome]

И на мобильных устройствах в Google Chrome отображается также,как и в консоли разработчика Chrome.

Comment: мета-тег "viewport" есть? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no" />`

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров Поставил - не помогло